# Can't share exported excel from SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

So i've been wasting a lot of time trying to solve this with no luck.

Someone in my team created a excel file by using "Export to excel". On her PC it works perfectly, however...nobody else can refresh the data from sharepoint online list.

I asked her for the connection file (LISTNAME.iqy), but i cant change the default one thats in the excel (if i go to Data, queries & connections -> connection properties -> definition and connection file). If i replace the connection file location (which shows on her C:/user etc) with the connection file location that she gave me (the same one from the settings) i get an error as in "Data will not be identical" and it removes the connection file location entirely.

Any idea how to fix this ? The excel export was done from a personal view, but afaik in the past sharing working without issues.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reproduce the issue from another personal view in your environment? Since personal views cannot be shared, this likely the reason that you're running into this issue.

I would also suggest re-creating her personal view as a public view (if that's not too much work) so that you can share it as needed and have others refresh the data connection.

Cheers,

-Drew

Comment: Thing is i thought about the personal view not being shareable, however she told me that there were other views that she shared the excel for and they work without problems. I'll see if i can create a view, but i dont really want that if it can be avoided.

Comment: I confirm Drew's answer. Excel accesses a view and if the view is not shared, the file won't be shareable. Your colleague was probably using a public view last time without realizing it.